# Converting multiple commands into a for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

It gets annoying to retype the commands in the terminal so many times.

Basically, instead of just running these commands for ogg_2x2 or ogg_1x1 like in the examples in the image, I need to run these commands for all i in **datasets** (the output of the cell above).

What I came up with is this, but I'm pretty sure I messed up the i's and $'s since I don't know how to use them:

```bsh
datasets=("input" "the" "elements" "of" "datasets" "from" "the" "notebook")
for i in "${datasets[@]}"; do
  ls *$i*mpin>$i.txt
  multipht list=$i.txt x=2 y=3 mag=4 err=5 jd=1 auto outfile=multipht_$i.out
  solvepht infile=multipht_$i.out outfile=$i.out varstar=0
done
```

[image: the commands that need to be run for all i in datasets]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, [edit] your questions and copy&paste the commands you want to run **as text**. This will allow us to copy them to an answer.

Comment: Yes, please don't post screenshots. Not only can we not copy data from them, they can't be searched, are useless for screen readers and this particular image is very unclear and hard to read. That said, is there anything wrong with the command you are using? Does it work? Does it do whatever it is that it is supposed to do?

Answer (score -1):

Please try following

```
for i in "input" "the" "elements" "of" "datasets" "from" "the" "notebook"
do
  ls *${i}*mpin>${i}.txt
  multipht list=${i}.txt x=2 y=3 mag=4 err=5 jd=1 auto outfile=multipht_${i}.out
  solvepht infile=multipht_${i}.out outfile=${i}.out varstar=0
done
```

Comment: How is this any different from what the user is already doing?

Comment: @Kusalananda 1. of all it does execute in bash script and Original one doesnt. 2. Variable i is in curly brackets '{' which is the variables should be used and good practice. 3. what is OP has missed '*' between say $impin then it is looking for variable impin instead of var i. 4. I have removed the dataset itself to make it simple. 5. I hope these are good enough reasons.

Comment: 1. The user's script has no errors. 2. `${i}` is exactly equivalent to `$i`. What you should have done is _double quote_ the `$i` as `"$i"`. There's no benefit added with the curly braces. 3. There is no `$impin` in the user's code. 4. This is no improvement IMHO. 5. It's not clear from the question if there is an actual issue with the code.

Comment: 1. Itried to run USER script - gave me errors 2. no ${i} is not equal to $i, please recheck. 3. if '*' is missed while typing "ls *$i*mpin>$i.txt" then it becomes "ls $impin>$i.txt"  and it looks for variable "impin" instead of "i". some times invisible characters are typed which can create problem so its better to use curly braces ${i} in my experience.

Comment: 1. The only errors I got was not having the needed programs installed. 2. The only difference is that if the variable is immediately followed by a character that is valid in a variable name, then the curly braces will be needed.  There is no such issue in this code. 3. There is no missing `*`. The only issue is not double quoting the variable expansions.  Again, it is not clear from the question what the issue actually is.

Comment: ok
I'll let the OP comment or give more info then . take care .